# Django channels Disconect after closing the tab

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I'm new to Django channels and I'm building a simple chatroom. With this chatroom, I want to disconnect a user if he closes the browser tab and if he reopens the tab with the same link, I want to reconnect him to the same chat that he was. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to reconnect to the same WebSocket, you just connect again to the same URL. From the client (browser) side you can use the example JavaScript code:

```
webSocket = new WebSocket('ws:/localhost:8000/ws/chat/');
```

The server side (the "backend", i.e., Django Channels) closes the connection when there are no clients connected.

What you probably mean is that you would like to have access to the chat history, yes? As I understand the WebSocket it is a communication protocol (in some sense similar to the HTTP). So it is used just to send the messages, not to store them. You should store the messages somewhere anyway, e.g., in the database. Then, on the "reconnect" you in fact get the messages from the database via `views`, or, in a different fashion, with the `consumers`.

Hope that helps. You would have to specify a concrete scenario for me to help you further.

Comment: Does this works if i refresh the browser? Sorry if I didn't specify, but when I refresh the browser it immediately disconnect me from my session. And I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Unfortunately, it pretty much has to happen. I mean, on refreshing the session (websocket connection) is disconnected, and then started again. The re-connection is most probably handled/triggered by the JavaScript code on the browser side of your application (websocket client). Think of a WebSocket as a kind of a constant HTTP connection, but at some point this connection has to be terminated.

Why would you like to keep the connection after the refresh? The connection will still be there, although disconnected and connected again.

Comment: Maybe you can increase the timeout on the server-side to "wait a bit" for the client (browser) in case of refresh, but it is not how WebSocket (and Django Channels) are designed, sorry. I hope that helps you anyway.

Comment: See also the documentation on closing the connection (handling the connection being closed) on the backend side: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/consumers.html#closing-consumers